# redirect to another page using header()

Tags: php, html

I want to handle when user input "examp" it will redirect to "examp.php".
I think it's pretty simple but I haven't been able to get it right, please help. Thanks very much <3

```
$search = $_GET['search'];
if ($search == 'examp') {
    header("location: examp.php");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: "I haven't been able to get it right" is not really useful debugging information. Your small amount of code, doesn't tell us anything other than there's no obvious syntax errors. Clarify your question; what are you trying to do, what have you tried, what did you expect and what is actually happening. "not working" is not an error.

Comment: Are you generating any HTML content **before** trying to use `header`? Is `error_reporting` turned on? Is the target page `examp.php` within the same directory as the script attempting to redirect?

Answer (score -1):

You should check out the php documentation about header redirection.

[php header](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.header.php)

Also if you redirect to another page, your exit(); won't work because you're not on that page anymore.. I think you're missing the protocol start http/https://

edit:
It's just a guess, but aren't you looking for an include or require function? That incorporates your php file into the existing one and exits after exit() function. If yes check out:

[Include](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.include.php)

[require](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.require.php)

Comment: Please share more details. `exit` after sending a header is common practise